# Apache Zeppelin, Deleted notebook

Tags: apache-zeppelin, file-recovery

I've restarted my Apache Zeppelin after an accidental close.
I don't see my notebook on the Home screen :o!!
When I list the notebook directory on the terminal, I see several codes for directories. One of them corresponds to my lost notebook, but when I list the files contained (note.json) ..it has 0 bytes.

It's very important to recover this notebook.
Can anyone help me?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unfortunately, that means the note has been lost. It is recommended to have 2 notebook repo so that you have at least another copy of your note. See https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.7.3/storage/storage.html#storage-in-zeppelinhub

Comment: Thank you a lot for the advice. Next time it will save me the painful task of re-coding.